# Viewing the named security attributes for token in windbg (kernel mode)

Tags: windows, windbg, windows-kernel

When examining the tokens in user mode windbg !token command prints the named attributes in Security Attributes Information section. E.g.

```
Security Attributes Information:
 00 Attribute Name: TSA://ProcUnique
    Value Type  : TOKEN_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_UINT64
    Value[0]    : 496
    Value[1]    : 24531381
```

But when examining the token in kernel debug this information is not displayed.

How can view the named attributes for the token when debugging in kernel mode?

Comment: I've found a workaround. The token object can be examined via dt nt!_TOKEN. Then you can look at +0x308 pSecurityAttributes field, there will be the list called SecurityAttributesList within _AUTHZBASEP_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES_INFORMATION. You can examine its entries, via dq to find UNICODE_STRING structures near the entry start. In my case (win11 23H2 x64) it was like +0x20 offset. And see UNICODE_STRING.Buffer value to get the attribute name

Comment: Yep spot on! It's a bit more complicated than that but you are on the right track. In the `_AUTHZBASEP_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES_INFORMATION` follow the linked list in `SecurityAttributesList` you'll land on a undocumented struct which is [visible here](https://github.com/winsiderss/systeminformer/blob/f94e66766e4951d2835b7449e99cedea3ef5e997/phnt/include/ntseapi.h#L158). Be wary that the `ValueType` of this struct indicates what you have at that location, it's not necessarily a UNICODE_STRING (only if type is `TOKEN_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_STRING` (3) in this case).